# How do I reference my MongoDB data in NodeJS, and then add it to a Discord.JS message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, discord.js

I'm trying to pull an array of data from a MongoDB database, and while the code is rusty (and I do want some corrections on it if it could be done better or is missing something or is wrong), it should be taking the array, finding the "user" and "description" objects, and then putting them into a discord.js message.

I've tried referencing the objects individually, making them strings, parsing the data, but I still cant find out how to do it. Heres the code I've been using.

```
  module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    const url = 'mongodb+srv://something:something@something/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
    const assert = require('assert');
    try {
        function remindersChecker() {
            let mongoClientPromise = MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, client) {
                const db = client.db("reminders");
                let date = new Date().getTime();
                let now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
                db.collection("reminders").find().toArray(function (err, result) {
                    let data = JSON.toObject();
                    console.log(data);
                    let user = data.author
                    let description = data.description
                    console.log(user);
                    user.send("I have a reminder for you! " + description)
                })
            })
        }
        remindersChecker()
    } catch(err) {
        catchError()
    }

}}
     module.exports.help = {
        name: "check"
    }
```

(The command is temporary and will be used on a setTimeout later, hence the function rather than just plain old code.)

Thanks! And I hope I can get help soon.

Comment: It would be great if you could tell us what happens with your current code - is an error thrown, does it return an empty array etc? However from a quick look, the data returned from your `.find()` is put into an object called `result`, but you are not referencing it. I imagine `console.log(data)` is returning null. Try `console.log(result)` to see if your `.find()` is returning data and in what format. Also I don't believe JSON.toObject() is a valid method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Comment: When I run the code and I print the user varible it comes out as undefined, thats as much as I'm getting though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably some more information would be great to better understand the problem.
from what i can see here, you are receiving an object from your database and converting it into an array here:

```
db.collection("reminders").find().toArray(function (err, result) {...
```

now that array is actually that result obtained from the callback and you are not using it at all, you probably have to iterate on that.

plus i remember that I used to write

```
...find({})..
```

to search in the database as for SELECT*FROM in SQL. maybe that can help too.

hope this helps.